Find maximum likelihood estimators of the mean and variance a given distribution
I am given a density function $f_X(x|a)$.
Given a random sample $x_1, x_2, \cdots , x_n$, I calculated the maximum likelihood estimator for the variable $a$. Let's call it $\bar{a}$.
Now, I was asked to calculate the maximum likelihood estimators of the mean and variance of the distribution for the given sample.
I know how to calculate both $E_X(x)$ and $V_X(x)$ in an expression of $a$.
So my questions here is do I just place the value I found $\bar{a}$ in the expression of $E_X(x)$ and $V_X(x)$, or do I need to take the expressions of $E_X(x)$ and $V_X(x)$ and derive them and compare to $0$ without any regard to the value of $\bar{a}$.
Help would be appreciated!

As you realized, the density is parametrized by $a$, we can easily see that the mean and the variance are functions of $a$:
\begin{align}
m(a) &= E_X(x|a) = \int xf(x|a)\,\mathrm{d}x\,,\\
v(a) &= V_X(x|a) = E_X(x^2|a) - m^2(a)\,.
\end{align}
Now, the invariance property of the ML estimator states that if $\bar{a}$ is the ML estimator of $a$, and we have any function $y=g(a)$, then the ML estimator of $y$ is given by $\bar{y}=g(\bar{a})$. Hence, in your problem,
\begin{align}
\bar{m} = m(\bar{a})\,,\\
\bar{v} = v(\bar{a})\,.\\
\end{align}
